# Apple mach-o linked (Id) Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have all the relevant frameworks added, and all relevant files are imported. In fact, if i remove the import, it gives me all the method not found errors. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Ld /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.app/Journal normal i386
    cd "/Users/Andrew/Dropbox/Developer/Dear Me/Version 1.0/XCode/Journal/Journal"
    setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.1.sdk -L/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Intermediates/Journal.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.build/Objects-normal/i386/Journal.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-arc -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50100 -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -o /Users/Andrew/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Journal-acrxfhgfvgofuyczzlzmnzunciov/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Journal.app/Journal

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_rectForRectWithInset", referenced from:
      -[JButton drawRect:] in JButton.o
  "_createRoundedRectForRect", referenced from:
      -[JButton drawRect:] in JButton.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

EDIT:

From these lines of code:

```
CGRect borderRect = rectForRectWithInset(self.bounds, 0.5);
CGMutablePathRef borderPath = createRoundedRectForRect(borderRect, 4);
```

They reference a class with those methods in. It works in another project i have, with the same imports, the same referenced methods, the same imported framework.

Comment: Can you show us the two lines of code that are generating these errors?  Also, what frameworks exactly have you added?

Comment: I couldn't find those methods in Apple's frameworks.  Do you know what framework they're supposed to be in?  There are equivalents in QuartzCore/CoreGraphics (as mentioned in the comments of the answer below), so I'd recommend going with those.

Answer (score 3):

a linker error most likely indicates that you missed to include a framework in your Build Phases of your target.

I don't know the implementation of the mentioned functions, but I assume, you missed to include either CoreGraphics or QuartzCore. And you need to import there main header-files.

Comment: No, neither of those functions are in any Apple frameworks. (Although there are equivalents that are -- `CGRectInset()` and `+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:]`.)